# How to get same result as height in vw but with percentages?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the height depend on the width of the browser. Currently I'm using the new viewport width unit to make it consistent on all screens. I do prefer percentage though as it has larger browser support. Is there any way to make this work with percentages?

For example, if I use height: 30% and change the height of my browser the height changes too, which I honestly don't want. I just want it to change when the width changes. I am aware of padding, but is it really a good way of solving things? Seems to be inconsistent between browsers.

I would like to hear some feedback from you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding is indeed the best way to do this — and browser support is utterly consistent (unlike the viewport width unit).

```
.wrapper {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

With the following markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

This will produce a square container whose height matches available width.

Comment: do you think I can achieve something similar with absolute elements and their position value top and bottom?

Comment: The problem is that `height`, `top` and `bottom` will all be calculated relative to the nearest relative parent's height — padding is the only attribute that acts relative to the actual element's width: strange, inconvenient, awkward — but sadly true!